# How to select multiple images in android / whatsapp

Tags: android, image, imageview, onactivityresult

Is there any way to upload images as we do with Whatsapp.

In Watsapp when i try to attach/send a file it shows that **"tap and hold to select multiple"**. and an **"OK"** button comes on the right corner.

Could someone tell me how to achieve that?.

when i tried I am only able to select a Single Image without using any external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom gallery to select multiple images from gallery

Refer this [link.](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/#comment-836)